# Using JavaMail API to send Email in Android App

Tags: android, eclipse, jakarta-mail

My `sendEmail()` function works in Eclipse with straight Java and I can send emails without any issue, but once I plug the function into my Android application none of the emails are being sent. I have added the `javax.mail` and `javax.activation` JARs to my build path in both cases. Here is the code for the function and then the LogCat reading. On a button click `sendEmailCustomer()` is called and nothing occurs. Any suggestions are more than appreciated.

```
public void sendEmailCustomer() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.stmp.user", "user");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new Authenticator() {
                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    String username = "user";
                    String password = "password";
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            });
    EditText e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterEmail);
    String to = e.toString();
    String from = "user";
    String subject = "Testing...";
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    try {
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        msg.setRecipient(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(
                to));
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setText("Did you get this?");
        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.send(msg);
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(exc.toString());
        builder.setTitle("Error!");
        builder.setNeutralButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

    }
}
```

Updated LogCat errors. It sounds like the application cannot access the internet even though it has permission in my manifest. Why is this?

```
04-03 12:38:07.166: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(2528): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
04-03 12:38:07.166: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(2528):    InputConnection =               
  com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection@411c5f28, active client = false
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending Email in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to fix [these common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes), and [this mistake](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#send).  You might just want to copy [this code for connecting to Gmail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail).  If that still doesn't work for you, follow [these debugging steps](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) to get more information so we can help you.

Note also that you can use the [latest JavaMail jar file](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Download_JavaMail_1.5.1_Release) instead of the older mail.jar file linked to above.

Comment: Specifically it was the transport/send parts of this that helped me out. Thank you for the references.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're referencing your JAR libraries in your project and at the same time, use the Android version of [JavaMail](https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/downloads/list) too.

Comment: I believe this was an issue since I did take it straight from my other Eclipse application and didn't even think about changing libs. Thank you. I no longer am getting the LogCat errors but the emails are still not coming through. But as I said, thank you for this catch.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this lines in your "AndroidManifest.xml" file

```
<manifest... >
....

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

....
</manifest>
```

maybe your problem is with the internet permission.

Comment: I did have the first line you suggest I add in place, I added the second and am still getting the same error. Thank you for your time and energy!

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2033124/1008639) SO thread for the solution. I also reccomend checking the permissions in your `AndroidManifest.xml` like SUNDAY suggested.